# How to send and receive SMS and calls using USB modem?

Tags: networking, 19.10, usb-modem, 4g

I have recently got a Huawei e3372 4G LTE USB modem and I have inserted a Jio SIM into it. I had configured it properly and can use the data connection well, but I cannot understand how to send and receive SMS and calls from that modem. I have seen lots of posts to do this, but I got no positive results from those procedures. What is the exact way of doing this, especially in Ubuntu 19.10?

Comment: for sms and ussd try `modemmanager-gui`

Comment: I am already using that. See this post [SMS not working in ModemManager GUI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1245070/sms-not-working-in-modemmanager-gui/1247452#1247452)