# SMS not working in ModemManager GUI

Tags: networking, usb-modem

I have got a **Huawei 4G LTE USB modem** and have successfully connected and activated it in Ubuntu 20.04. I can use the data connection from a SIM card, but I haven't got the SMS as well as other functionalities such as USSD to work yet.

I came to know about a software called **ModemManager GUI**, but it too cannot send and receive SMS and USSD codes. It shows an error while sending SMSs:
[image]

Same for USSD:
[image]

I need at least one of these features to know my current data balance. How can I proceed?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible modemmanger does not support sms or ussd for this modem. another way to check ussd and sms is to use picocom by giving AT commands.

install picocom:

`sudo apt install picocom`

to be able to issue the AT commands you would have to disable the internet connection to free the modem

next find out the various ports of the modem:
ls /dev/ttyU*

usually you would be presented with three ports;

```
dialogue port (ie 1st port) is /dev/ttyUSB0
audio  port (ie 2nd port) is /dev/ttyUSB1   (audio and microphone if supported)
sms & internet aka data  port (ie 3rd port) is /dev/ttyUSB3
```

start picocom on the dialogue port:

```
sudo picocom -c /dev/ttyUSB0
the -c means local echo on, making AT commands visible as you type
```

now check USSD:

```
AT+CUSD=1,"*333#"
```

sometimes the response may be in unreadable characters. to correct that, before 
issuing the ussd command, you would have to set the modem to gsm mode with

```
AT+CSCS="GSM"
```

followed by the ussd command

Comment: Should I type those AT commands while picocom is running? In the same terminal?

Comment: yes. type them while picocom is running

Comment: But, it constantly prints something or the other, it does not let me type something.

Comment: if possible kindly copy and paste the errors or warnings you are getting

Comment: Here is the output after running `sudo picocom -c /dev/ttyUSB0` : [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VFXhX.png)

Comment: These lines are being printed again and again with an interval of 1 second: `^SYSINFOEX:2,3,0,1,,6,"LTE",101,"LTE"

OK

^HCSQ:"LTE",62,54,181,24

^RSSI:28

^HCSQ:"LTE",64,54,176,20

^HCSQ:"LTE",61,53,181,22

+CSQ: 27,99`

Comment: @Puspam you could still go ahead and type it (better still do a copy and paste) then press Enter. disregard the lines that are being printed. if it don't work start picocom on the other ports availble from `ls /dev/ttyU*`

Comment: Thanks for the idea. But now, after I enter `AT+CUSD=1,"*333#"` it gives `+CME ERROR: 100`. It happens even if I run `AT+CSCS="GSM"` before that. I have only two tty ports available and none of them worked.

Comment: hm. pls try again with the internet disconnected

Comment: Tried it, but still the same problem `+CME ERROR: 100`.